# Simple DB policy being ignored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to use AWS IAM to generate temporary tokens for a mobile app. I'm using the AWS C# SDK.

Here's my code...

**The token generating service**

```
public string GetIAMKey(string deviceId)
    {
        //fetch IAM key...

        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("MyKey", "MyAccessId");

        var sts = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(credentials);

        var tokenRequest = new GetFederationTokenRequest();
        tokenRequest.Name = deviceId;
        tokenRequest.Policy = File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/policy.txt"));
        tokenRequest.DurationSeconds = 129600;

        var tokenResult = sts.GetFederationToken(tokenRequest);

        var details = new IAMDetails { SessionToken = tokenResult.GetFederationTokenResult.Credentials.SessionToken, AccessKeyId = tokenResult.GetFederationTokenResult.Credentials.AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey = tokenResult.GetFederationTokenResult.Credentials.SecretAccessKey, };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);
    }
```

**The client**

```
var iamkey = Storage.LoadPersistent<IAMDetails>("iamkey");

        var simpleDBClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(iamkey.AccessKeyId, iamkey.SecretAccessKey, iamkey.SessionToken);

        try
        {
            var details = await simpleDBClient.SelectAsync(new SelectRequest { SelectExpression = "select * from mydomain" });

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Storage.ClearPersistent("iamkey");
        }
```

**The policy file contents**

> {   "Statement":[{      "Effect":"Allow",      "Action":"sdb:* ",      "Resource":"arn:aws:sdb:eu-west-1:* :domain/mydomain*"      }   ]}

I keep  getting the following error...

> User (arn:aws:sts::myaccountid:federated-user/654321) does not have permission to perform (sdb:Select) on resource (arn:aws:sdb:us-east-1:myaccountid:domain/mydomain)

Notice that my policy file clearly specifies two things

1. region should be ***eu-west-1***
2. allowed action is a wild-card, ie, allow everything

But the exception thrown claims that my user doesn't have permission to ***us-east-1***

Any ideas as to  why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out.

You have to set the region endpoint on your call to the service from the client.

So

```
var simpleDBClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(iamkey.AccessKeyId, iamkey.SecretAccessKey, iamkey.SessionToken, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
```